# Templating an input string

Tags: java, string

My method needs to check if a given string is equal to a defined template, actually it does not produce output as expected.

Inputstring: 18122016 with template "  .  ." will return correctly "18.12.2016"

Inputstring: 15:00 with template "  :" will return "15:500" which is wrong, expected was 15:00

Maybe someone has a clearer solution than mine?

These are my testcases:

```
@Test
public void testDoCandidateWithTextTemplate() { 

    ArrayList<String> tWords = new ArrayList<>();
    tWords.add(":");
    String result = VORecognitionResultsImpl.doCandidateWithTextTemplate("1500", tWords, "  :");
    assertEquals("15:00", result);
    result = VORecognitionResultsImpl.doCandidateWithTextTemplate("15:00", tWords, "  :");
    assertEquals("15:00", result);

    result = VORecognitionResultsImpl.doCandidateWithTextTemplate("18122016", tWords, "  .  .");
    assertEquals("18.12.2016", result);

    result = VORecognitionResultsImpl.doCandidateWithTextTemplate("1437", tWords, "  ,");
    assertEquals("14,37", result);      

}
```

Here is the method

```
public static String doCandidateWithTextTemplate(String tmpTextCandidate,
                                           ArrayList<String> tWords,
                                           String textTemplate)
{
    if( textTemplate == null ) return tmpTextCandidate;
    if( textTemplate.length() == 0 ) return tmpTextCandidate;
    StringBuffer outText = new StringBuffer();
    int currentIndex = 0;

    boolean isInserted = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < textTemplate.length();i++){  
        currentIndex = i;
        if (textTemplate.charAt(i) == ' '){
            if (!isInserted){
                outText.append(tmpTextCandidate.charAt(i));
            }
            else{
                outText.append(tmpTextCandidate.charAt(i-1));
                isInserted = false;
            }
        }
        else{
            if (textTemplate.charAt(i) != tmpTextCandidate.charAt(i)){
                outText.append(textTemplate.charAt(i));
                isInserted = true;

            }
        }
    }

    if (currentIndex < tmpTextCandidate.length()-1){
        outText.append(tmpTextCandidate.substring(currentIndex-1, tmpTextCandidate.length()));
    }

    return outText.toString();

}
```

Comment: your code can also break in cases when input is "18123016" output is 18.13.3016 there is a bug in your index calculation. You just cant do index-1 just once, it has to be persistent and my suggestion is using two indexes i and j, which will make your code more readable and easy to correct

Answer (score 3):

Your counter (`currentIndex`) is off by one. A typical corner case issue.

For the `1500` -> `15:500` break: After the `for` condition breaks, the `i` is `3` but the `currentIndex` is `2` because you didn't enter the loop the fourth time. So when you do `tmpTextCandidate.substring(currentIndex-1, tmpTextCandidate.length())` that is `tmpTextCandidate.substring(1, 4)` which is `500` for the part of the `outString` after the separator (:) .

Your first test case succeeds because you have two counts of separator (.) So, as it sometimes happen, two errors produce the right output, but error is still present.

So, you should only increment `currentIndex` if you take char from the `tmpTextCandidate` and make sure it's not off by one, like it is now.

EDIT: I've fixed the mistakes in your function, without changing the approach.

```
public static String doCandidateWithTextTemplate(String tmpTextCandidate,
                                       ArrayList<String> tWords,
                                       String textTemplate)
{
    if( textTemplate == null ) return tmpTextCandidate;
    if( textTemplate.length() == 0 ) return tmpTextCandidate;
    StringBuffer outText = new StringBuffer();
    int currentIndex = 0;
    String tmp = textTemplate;
    while(!tmp.isEmpty()) {
        while(tmp.indexOf(" ") == 0) {
            outText.append(tmpTextCandidate.charAt(currentIndex));
            tmp = tmp.substring(1);
            currentIndex++;
        }
        if(!(tmp.charAt(0) == tmpTextCandidate.charAt(currentIndex))) { //This is in case you want both inputs "15:00" as well as the "1500" to output "15:00"
            outText.append(tmp.charAt(0));
        }
        tmp = tmp.substring(1);
    }
    while(currentIndex < tmpTextCandidate.length()) {
        outText.append(tmpTextCandidate.charAt(currentIndex++));
    }
    return outText.toString();
}
```

Note that this is not the optimal solution and also, the `tWords` parameter isn't used anywhere in your (and consequently my) implementation of the `doCandidateWithTextTemplate` function.

Comment: Thanks for the response, can post the corrected code?

Comment: I'm at work right now and I think you'll learn more if you debug it yourself. But I'll check back in about three hours and post the correct implementation if you still have trouble.

Comment: It would be great if you post it, Thanks